# How can I find non ASCI in content in file in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In batch script I want find content in a.txt
in a.txt I have more records how to check record contain nonaci and write to b.txt ?
I have code to mid string but fail too

```
@echo off


setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL 
set _char= "123456789~abcdef0"
SET /A _startchar=1
SET /A _length=1


for /L %%a in (32,1,125) do (

  cmd /c exit %%a
  
  
  echo !=exitcodeAscii!
  if "!=exitcodeAscii!" EQU "%_char%" echo -- %%a
  CALL SET _substring=!!_char:!_startchar!,2!!
  ECHO !_substring! --- !_startchar!
  SET /A _startchar=!_startchar! + 1
   
)
```

Comment: The ascii exit code will never be equal to the variable `_char`.  What are you trying to accomplish with that line of code? The following line of code is incorrect: `CALL SET _substring=!!_char:!_startchar!,2!!`. This should be using double percent symbols to properly expand the variable to the value and you are missing the tilde.  `CALL SET _substring=%%_char:~!_startchar!,2%%`

Comment: Hi @Squashman , Thank you but it is unsucessfull
I replaced
for /L %%a in (32,1,125) do (

  cmd /c exit %%a
  
  
  echo !=exitcodeAscii!
  if "!=exitcodeAscii!" EQU "%_char%" echo -- %%a
  CALL SET _substring=%%_char:~!_startchar!,2%%
  ECHO !_substring! --- !_startchar!
  SET /A _startchar=!_startchar! + 1
   
) but it is failed  when I echo it is space not have any value 
CALL SET _substring=%%_char:~!_startchar!,2%%
  ECHO !_substring! --- !_startchar!

Comment: Code updates to your question should go in your question. Please [edit] your question with your new code.  Regardless, I wasn't trying to solve your question, I was just bringing attention to the few code errors I saw. The code I gave your does resolve the syntax issue you were having.  The code will most certainly echo a space once the `startchar` variable is greater then the length of the string you are trying to parse.  In this case the `_char` variable only has 20 characters.  So after that the substring will display a space.  This is pretty basic logic you could figure out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following defines a variable with valid Ascii characters (excluding `"`, handled by substitution) for character by character comparison.

**Edit: Changes made to improve performance and ensure any possible ASCII input is handled correctly .**

```bat
@Echo off

 For /f "tokens=4 delims=: " %%G in ('CHCP')Do Set "Restore_Codepage=CHCP %%G > nul"
 Set "Return[Len]=" & Set "Return[String]=" & Set "{input}="

 Setlocal DISABLEDelayedExpansion
REM the label marker ":#" is used within this script to delimit help output.

:# 
:# ========================= ASCII string filter v3.1 by T3RRY ======================
 Rem - This script iterates over an input string character by character and tests
 Rem each character against a a whitelist of printable ASCII characters, with
 Rem succesful matches used to build a new string containing only printable
 Rem ASCII characters.
 Rem - Switch /R modifies this script to into a testing tool
 Rem   to check if a string contains any NonASCII or nonprintable ASCII characters.
 Rem   - Errorlevel 0 indicates the string contains only printable ASCII characters
 Rem   - A Positive errorlevel is returned containing the 1 indexed position of the
 Rem     first NonASCII or nonprintable ASCII character found.
 Rem - Execution time increases as string length increases. Each character in the
 Rem   string is tested against a whitelist containing 95 printable ASCII characters.
:# 
:# Usage: Filepath <"String"> [ /P | /R ] | [ -? | /? | -help ]
:#
:# Rem to use from another batch file:
:# For /f delims^= %%G in ('FilePath "string"')Do Echo(%%G
:# 
:# Accepts input String via doublequoted argument - reads %* and trims " \P" or " \R"
:# switches if present
:# - No escaping of characters in the argument is required
:# - If unbalanced doublequotes exist in the string all doublequotes will be Removed.
:# 
:# Use Switch /P to preserve original spaces
:#  - Default behaviour is to Remove all double spaces from the string.
:# 
:# Use Switch /R to reject input containing NonASCII characters
:#  - If non ASCII character encountered, returns a positive errorlevel
:#   ( the 1 indexed position of first non ASCII character encountered )
:# 
 Rem Version changes 09/Dec/2021 :
 Rem - Changed input method to handle cases where qouted args contain
 Rem   standard delims within quotes IE: "string "substring=text""
 Rem Version changes 08/Dec/2021 :
 Rem - Added Help Switches -? /? and -help
 Rem - Added switch: /R 
 Rem   - Reject strings containing non ASCII characters. Default: Strip NonASCCi
 Rem     characters from the string.
 Rem     Note: this switch does not define Return[Len] or Return[String]
 Rem Version changes 07/Dec/2021 :
 Rem - Rewritten for much faster performance - NOTE:
 Rem   - Added Switch: /P
 Rem    - Preserve all whitespace. Default: multiple spaces truncated to single.
 Rem - Renamed variable for returning String : Return[String]
 Rem - Added variable Return[Len] to return 0 indexed string length.
 Rem - Corrected handling of completely non ASCII strings to return empty / 0 Len
 Rem ** Utilize alternate data stream to store variable containing printable ASCII
 Rem    characters so the variable only needs to be generated on first execution.
 Rem     ** Requires this batch file to be run from an NTFS drive.
:# =================================================================================

 Set "ASCII= !"
 2> nul (
  more < "%~f0:ASCII.dat" > nul || (
   Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   For /l %%i in (34 1 126) Do (
    Cmd /c Exit %%i
    Set "ASCII=!ASCII!!=ExitCodeAscii!"
   )
   >"%~f0:ASCII.dat" (Echo(Set ^^"ASCII=!ASCII!")
   ENDLOCAL
 ))

 Set "ASCII="
 For /f "delims=" %%G in ('More ^< "%~f0:ASCII.dat"')Do %%G
 If not Defined ASCII (
  2> nul (
   Powershell.exe -c "Remove-item -path '%~nx0' -Stream '*'"
  )
  1>&2 Echo(An error has occured. Ensure "%~nx0" is located on an NTFS drive.
  Pause
  ENDLOCAL
  Exit /b 1
 )

 Rem Maximum stringlength to support. Modify here to propagate to RemoveChar loop and Return[Len]
 REM maximum 1015 chars due to input reading method.
 Set "SupportLength=1015"
 Set "{input}="

::====================================================================================================
rem :: input capture method by Dave Benham : https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4288#p23980
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>"%temp%\getArg.txt" <"%temp%\getArg.txt" (
  setlocal disableExtensions
  set prompt=#
  echo on
  for %%a in (%%a) do rem . %*.
  echo off
  endlocal
  set /p "args="
  set /p "args="
  set "{input}=!args:~7,-2!"
  set "count=!args:~7,-2!"
)

del "%temp%\getArg.txt"

::====================================================================================================

Rem the below line can be used to Remove the aleternate data stream this file creates.
 Rem Powershell -c "Remove-item -path '%~nx0' -Stream '*'"

 CHCP 65001 > nul
 If not defined {input} (
  Echo(Demo:
Rem escaped for definition in DelayedExpansion environment
  Set "{input}=this is a demo) * ^! & ☺ ^= ¶ | ^! <. ~ ^^ & %% ▒ ╔ § ♣ This"
  Set {input}
 )

REM handle help switches

 Set {input} | %SystemRoot%\System32\Findstr.exe /Xli "{input}=\/? {input}=-? {input}=-help" > nul && (
  Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  For /f "tokens=2* delims=#" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Findstr.exe /blic:":# " "%~f0"')Do (
   Set "Usage=%%G"
   Echo(!Usage:Filepath=%~f0!
  )
  ENDLOCAL & ENDLOCAL
  Exit /b 0
 )

 Set Div="is=#", "1/(is<<9)"

 Set "{DQ}=1"
 Set ^"count=!count:"={DQ}!"

 2> nul Set "null=%count:{DQ}=" & Set /A {DQ}+=1& set "null=%"

 Set /A !Div:#=%{DQ}% %% 2! 2> nul || Set ^"{input}=!{input}:"=!"

REM handle nonhelp switches

 Set "ASCIISwitch[R]="
 Set "ASCIISwitch[P]="
 If defined {input} (
  Set {input} | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /Elic:" /P" > nul && (
   Set "{input}=!{input}:~0,-3!"
   Set "ASCIISwitch[P]=true"
  )
  Set {input} | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /Elic:" /R" > nul && (
   Set "{input}=!{input}:~0,-3!"
   Set "ASCIISwitch[R]=true"
 ))

Rem Remove outer doublequotes from input argument if not already removed due to unbalanced quoting.

 If .^%{input}:~0,1%^%{input}:~-1%. == ."". Set "{input}=!{input}:~1,-1!"

Rem RemoveChar loop - iterate over input character by character; Compare against each character in whitelist
Rem Appends ASCII Whitelist characters to New string unless /R switch used, in which case NonASCII characters
Rem  trigger an exit of the script with a positive errorlevel indicating the string is not ASCII.
Rem  the return value is the 1 indexed position of the first non ascii character encountered.

 Set "end=" & Set "New="
 For /l %%i in (0 1 %SupportLength%)Do If not "!{input}:~%%i,1!"=="" (
  Set "Char=!{input}:~%%i,1!"
  Set "ISAscii="
  For /l %%c in (0 1 94)Do If not "!ASCII:~%%c,1!" == "" (
   Set "C_Char=!ASCII:~%%c,1!"
   if "!Char!"=="!C_Char!" (
    Set "New=!New!!Char!"
    Set "ISAscii=true"
  ))
  If Defined ASCIISwitch[R] (
   If Not Defined ISAscii (
    Endlocal & Endlocal &  %Restore_Codepage%
    For /f "delims=" %%G in ('Set /A %%i+1')Do Exit /b %%G     
 )))

 Set "{Input}=!New!"
 If not Defined ASCIISwitch[P] (
  For /l %%i in (0 1 9)Do if defined {Input} Set "{Input}=!{Input}:  = !"
 )

 If defined {input} (
  Echo(!{input}!
  For /l %%i in (0 1 %SupportLength%)Do If not defined Return[Len] If "!{input}:~%%i,1!"=="" Set "Return[Len]=%%i"
 ) Else (
  Set "Return[Len]=0"
  Set "Return[String]="
 )

 ENDLOCAL & ENDLOCAL & Set "Return[Len]=%Return[Len]%" & Set "Return[string]=%{input}%" )
 %Restore_Codepage%

Exit /B 0
```

Comment: Hi @T3RR0R 
I try and it success but I also have  new problem if return nonasci will write log in file.
My problem is I can not reuse parameter in function (position of nonasci)
Because I need read all file txt in folder and in each file I need read all record ( 10 record ) if has record contain  nonasci will write logfile and replace nonsci by space if can .
Could you help me thank you.

Comment: base on your code
`Call:IsASCII Demo
  Call:IsASCII Ascii`
I add my code but it is not working 
` if  %%i  not equal 0 echo %Demo% >> log.txt`
Can you help me thank you very much